# How to Traverse directories and sub-directories starting from a directory c, where c is given as the input argument for your traversal script

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu

I want to write a shell script that will traverse the directory structure starting from a directory `c`, where `c` is given as the input argument for your traversal script.

- During traversal, I want each directory I have visited to be printed out on my screen.
- Along with the directories, I also want the subdirectories, the list of files, and their sizes printed out.
- Files that are greater than 1KB should be printed out.

I can only list files in a current directory but I cannot traverse through them.

This printed all the files in my directory Sample including the sizes and permissions. This is not what I want because I want to print directories, sub-directories, and files from any folder using the directories as input not just in a specific directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

for Sample in "$/Sample"/*
do
  ls -l
  #echo "$Sample"
done

#All this did was to print all the directories in my system. This is not what I want
#!/bin/bash

for d in "$dir"/*
do
  echo "$d"
done

#What I am working on now but it is giving me syntax errors near done. -d $file #prints out for directory, while -f $file print out files.
#!/bin/bash

  dir=$dir
for file in ${dir}/*; do
    if [[ -d $file ]]; then
        echo "$file:"
    if [[ -f $file ]]; then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Welcome, please share what you have tried.

Comment: If the solutions you found on the internet cover 80% of what you want, it should not be too hard to adapt the solutions so they cover the rest as well. To start from scratch, your solution should be centered on the `find` command. It's fundamental purpose is to visit all files in a directory tree, and it has numerous filters (size, file type, permissions and so on) as well as actions on the files thus found, such as the `exec` option.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` is not the best choice of shell for that. With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

zmodload zsh/stat || exit

(( $# != 0 )) || set .

files=($^argv/**/*(ND/,.LK+1))
(( $#files == 0 )) ||
  stat -Ln +size -- $files
```

Here `LK+1` selects files (regular files only with `.`) whose size is strictly greater than 1KiB (1024 bytes). For files greater than 1KB (1000 bytes), replace it with `L+1000`.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. Is there a different syntax for it.

Comment: @webnerd, which Unix-like OS you use is not very relevant here. zsh like bash predates Ubuntu and even Linux, but you need it to be installed. On Ubuntu, you (or the administrator) would need to run `apt install zsh zsh-doc` as `root` if zsh is not already installed.

Comment: It gave me errors like zmodload: command not found. Why do you think this is?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements can be satisfied by a single `find` command:

```
$ find path/to/dir \( -type d -o \( -type f -a -size +1024k \) \) -printf '%s %p\n'
```

This says:

- Select directories (`-type d`)
- OR (`-o`)
- ( Select files (`-type f`) AND (`-a`) larger than 1024KiB (`-size +1024k`) )
- Do a formatted print (`-printf`) of the file size in bytes, the file path and a newline (`%s %p\n`)

The parentheses are used for grouping but must be escaped with backslashes to prevent them being interpreted by the shell.

Further explanations are in `man find`.

This prints files that are larger than 1024k, not exactly 1024k.

Comment: Note that `-printf` and that `k` suffix are GNU extensions (the latter is now found in some other implementations).

Comment: Fair enough - I didn't mention it as OP tagged this Ubuntu so will be using GNU find. But maybe the casual browser won't notice that tag.

Comment: It works but I want my terminal to accept user inputs. Do you have an idea on how I'll do that? what is the command for that?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Nevermind! I have figured it out! Thank you so much! if only I can upvote your solution twice!